# Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) are loading pages redirected from .htaccess twice!

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect, safari, webkit

I have this problem. When you visit page where is PHP code:

```
$_SESSION['test']++;
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

And page is redirected throught .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php index.php?rw=1&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So in non-webkit browsers you will see 1, on next refresh 2, 3, 4, 5 ...
But in Chrome or Safari you will see 1, 3, 5, 7, ...

Does anybody have some idea how to solve it? I just need every page redirect to index.php and then load content ... but with every f***ed redirect it has same result ... twice loaded! So when there is a MySQL query, it is processed twice, ... :-/

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem was, that there were:

```
<iframe src="#"></iframe>
```

Webkit has got problems with it, and load pages twice ... so solution is

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/blankPage.html"></iframe>
```

It is all!!! After 10 hours of madness ... :-/