# Javascript file loading twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I am having a strange problem in Google Chrome. I am including a js file via script src tag. I place alert('test') in the file and when I load the page in Chrome, It alerts twice. In every other browser it alerts once. Is there any known cause for this?

Here is the code that loads the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

It appears this happens in Safari as well. Does not occur in IE and firefox.

Comment: please post the code that loads the javascript

Comment: Add `debugger;` to the beginning of your javascript code and then step-through setting break points in the Dev Tool.

Comment: Ok I did that and it seems to go over the same code twice as I keep clicking "step into next function call". It read from line 0 to the last line then goes back to 0 after the last line. After the second time going down the script it stops.

Comment: @John I ran a similar test and it alert() just once. You have something else going on

Comment: can you post the code from main.js?

Comment: I have a ajax request that gets conducted on load...but it does not load any files containing any headers or JS files. When I disable this request the problem stops. What could be causing this?

Comment: Nevermind the ajax request is NOT causing the problem. Weird.

Comment: @john as others have asked: We need some code. It could be almost anything.

Comment: Ok it appears to not be the JS at all because I used a dummy main.js file that contains only `alert('test')` and it executed this twice. It appears to be reloading all the headers twice for some reason.

Comment: I have found the problem...I had a hidden iframe in the page with a src set to "#" causing the page to load twice.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, please post it as an answer and accept it in a few days. That way those that have the same problem in the future will know what to do.

Answer (score 12):

I had this recently and eventually found out it was a chrome extension, specifically the cache killer extension

Comment: This was it for me too! Thank you! Looks like the page load-time is the same - it just reports the files are loading twice.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

[Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) are loading pages redirected from .htaccess twice!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493295/webkit-browsers-chrome-safari-are-loading-pages-redirected-from-htaccess-twic)

Comment: I found the problem - I had a hidden iframe in the page with its source set to "#". This causes the page to load again in the iframe in Chrome/Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this same problem in Chrome. I have some code that runs when the page loads and I have an alert inside that code. In every browser other than Chrome this code is run once, thus the alert displays once. In chrome the alert shows twice. I am not doing anything special, just running code when the onload event is triggered within `<body onload="somefunction()">`. I am not using links, iframes, or the Cache Killer extension. I tested it in Safari and the code is only being called once. This seems to be a Chrome specific problem.

I did some research and it appears this is a bug with Chrome. I found this link https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810

Depending on your specific situation, this page may give you a work around for the problem.

The problem does not seem to be fixed as of yet.